# Spring JPA Data: Query ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an entity with an elementCollection:

```
@Entity
class Customer {
  @Column(name = "id")
  int id;
  String name;
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
  Set<Address> addresses;
}

@Embeddable
class Address {
  @Column(name = "address_id")
  String id;
  String data;
}
```

of course the matching data on the db:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: me
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: customer
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: bigint
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: name
                  type: varchar(255)
        - createTable:
            tableName: address
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: customer_id
                  type: bigint
                   constraints:
                    nullable: false
             - column:
                  name: address_id
                  type: varchar(30)
              - column:
                  name: data
                  type: varchar(255)
        - addForeignKeyConstraint:
            baseTableName: address
            baseColumnNames: customer_id
            referencedTableName: customer
            referencedColumnNames: id
            constraintName: fk_customer_id
        - addUniqueConstraint:
            tableName: address
            name: unique_address_id
            columnNames: address_id
```

Note: address id is really a String!

Inserting, and reading works. But my goal is to select `Customer` by `Address.id`.

My goal:

```
interface CustomerJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
  XXXX // <-- insert solution here
}
```

My ideas for XXXX:

1. Using spring data JPA:

```
  Customer findByAddressWithId(String addressId);
```

Of course, this does not work, because the syntax is wrong. But I can't even find a description of the complete syntax for ElementCollections.

2. Using a custom query:

```
  @Query(value = "select c from Customer c join Address a where a.id = '?1'")
  Customer findByStreet(String addressId);
```

This one does not work because `a.id` can't be found.

Unfortunately, none of the above work.
Does anybody have any solution for `XXXX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embeddable classes representation don’t have a persistent identity of their own. Entity classes will have persistent identity of thier own.
Instances of the `Address` embeddable class here share the identity of the entity that owns it, that is `Customer`.
As embeddable classes exist only as the state of another entity, consider making Address as Entity if you require a persistent id `Addressid` for `Address`.
Otherwise, also check persistent provider specific annotations like `CollectionId`
[CollectionId.html](http://Embeddable%20classes%20representation%20don%E2%80%99t%20have%20a%20persistent%20identity%20of%20their%20own.%20Entity%20classes%20will%20have%20persistent%20identity%20of%20thier%20own.%20%20Instances%20of%20the%20Address%20embeddable%20class%20here%20share%20the%20identity%20of%20the%20entity%20that%20owns%20it,%20that%20is%20Customer.%20%20As%20embeddable%20classes%20exist%20only%20as%20the%20state%20of%20another%20entity,%20consider%20making%20Address%20as%20Entity%20if%20you%20require%20a%20persistent%20id%20Addressid%20for%20Address.%20%20Also%20check%20persistent%20provider%20specific%20annotations%20like%20CollectionID%20https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionId.html) and define addressid as a `collectionid`.